# can I store Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(".\\")); into a variable

Tags: java, folderbrowserdialog

If this is something that can be stored in a variable what type of variable would this be.   I apologize for not knowing how to ask this correctly however I am learning as OJT and am not familiar with all of the terminology yet.  Similarly if this has been answered before I was unsure how to find it.

I would like to store this in a variable solely for the sake of readability as this will be one of five inputs.

If this can not be accomplished, I will just enter it in as necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean store it as a variable? Do you want the string which points to the file be stored as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

`Desktop.open` has a `void` return type. That is it doesn't return anything. It just launches an application or throws an exception.

You can store the `Desktop` object in a variable.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(new File(".\\"));
```

Comment: So the first part is the instantiation of Desktop and the desktop.open(new File(".\\")) is considered an initialized variable?  Didn't realize I could break that up.  thanks!